# Is there a way to toggle the "Hidden" or "Read-Only" switches on a Windows file using PHP?

Tags: php, file, hidden, readonly

**UPDATED**

As the title says, is there a way to toggle the "Hidden" or "Read-Only" switch on Windows using PHP?

I'd like to do this without opening a shell `exec()` if possible.

Comment: "Hidden" in which sense and on which operating system?

Comment: Yes... Under *nix systems putting leading . in file name makes it 'hidden'

Comment: @deceze - Hidden, on Windows, in the sense where you have to toggle it in the "Folder Options | View" menu.  @playcat - thanks, Angus mentioned that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file can't be *hidden*, it's always in the file system. There's the *NIX convention that files starting with a `.` are not shown by default for certain operations (like the `ls` command), but only if you don't look hard enough. The same goes for Windows, but Windows handles it with file meta attributes.

What you can/should do is use file permissions to make the folder/file inaccessible to anybody who has no business accessing it. Use [`chmod`](http://php.net/chmod), [`chown`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) and [`chgrp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php) to do so from PHP. You may have to learn a bit about proper file system permissions though.

Comment: What does the "file meta attributes" part mean with respect to PHP?  Is there an answer hidden in there?

Comment: @Steve No. :) It just means that UNIX determines whether to show a file or not by looking whether or not its file name starts with a `.`. Windows saves meta attributes on a file and looks at those to make the same decision. It doesn't change the fact that that doesn't *hide* the file (in the sense that you're probably thinking), it just doesn't include it in *certain* operations (like Joe User looking at a folder in Windows Explorer).

Comment: @Steve Honestly I have no idea how to set these permissions/visibility flags on Windows. You should update your question to make clear that that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Those are exactly the operations I'm targeting. I don't know a better way to phrase the question without using Microsoft's terminology.

Answer (score 3):

To make a file "hidden" on Windows you can use

```
attrib +h yourfile.ext
```

To make a file "read-only" on Windows you can use

```
attrib +r yourfile.ext
```

To use these commands from PHP you just execute them using system or exec.

Also see : [Attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without opening a shell?

Comment: With standard PHP? Not that I know of. There could be a PHP module providing this functionality though (or you could write one yourself).

Answer (score 3):

While there are some reports on the web that PHP's chmod would indeed be able to set Windows attribute flags (at least the read-only flag) I could not reproduce this at all. 
So shelling out to an `attrib` command is the way to go.

**READ-ONLY on Windows and *nix**

Here is some code to set a file to read-only that will work on Windows and *nix:

```
// set file READ-ONLY (Windows & *nix)
$file = 'path/to/file.ext';
if(isset($_SERVER['WINDIR'])) {
    // Host OS is Windows
    $file = str_replace('/', '\\', $file);
    unset($res);
    exec('attrib +R ' . escapeshellarg($file), $res);
    $res = $res[0];
}else{
    // Host OS is *nix
    $res = chmod($file, 0444);
}
//$res contains result string of operation
```

Hints: 
Replacing '/' with '\' is important as the shell command (`attrib`) is not as tolerant to slashes as PHP is.
$res is unset in the Windows part because exec() appends to any existing value.

**HIDDEN on Windows**

If you want to set a file hidden, this would probably be a Windows only task:

```
// set file HIDDEN (Windows only)
$file = 'path/to/file.ext';
$file = str_replace('/', '\\', $file);
unset($res);
exec('attrib +H ' . escapeshellarg($file), $res);
$res = $res[0];
//$res contains result string of operation
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Unix you can make the file hidden by putting a dot (`.`) at the start of its name, and use the `chmod` function to make the file read-only. Not sure about Windows.

Comment: Thanks Angus will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For the file permissions, try `chmod` function:

```
<?php 
    chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode
?>
```

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php