# PHP windows create hidden files

Tags: php, windows, file, hidden

Is it possible to create hidden files/folders on windows using php (xampp)?
And if it is, how?

Comment: In wWindows you can make files hidden so that they won't be visible by default to the users, only to the OS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A file in Windows is hidden if it has the hidden attribute set on it. There is no built in function to do this, so you need to use [system](http://php.net/system)/[exec](http://php.net/exec) to execute the [attrib](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) application. Like this:

```
$file = 'test.txt';
system('attrib +H ' . escapeshellarg($file));
```

This will set the hidden (+H) flag on test.txt.

Answer (score 2):

You could call [`attrib`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx):

```
$filename = 'c:\\some\\file.txt';
exec('attrib +h '.$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set HIDDEN attribute of file on Windows
$file = 'path/to/file.ext';
$file = str_replace('/', '\\', $file);
unset($res);
exec('attrib +H ' . escapeshellarg($file), $res);
$res = $res[0];
//$res contains result string of operation
```

Hints: 
Replacing '/' with '\' is important as the shell command (attrib) is not as tolerant to slashes as PHP is.
$res is unset first because exec() appends to any existing value.

If you are looking for a way to set a file to **read-only** that will work on Windows AND *nix, then have a look at my answer to this other question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127640/430742