# How can I create a hidden file with php, when safe_mode is on

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm using windows on local and I want to hide or create a hidden file with php.

How can I do it?

**without using the sistem() or exec() because safe_mode is on**

EDIT:
resolve for a specific directory

http.conf:

```
< Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/specific/directory">
  php_admin_flag safe_mode off 
< /Directory>
```

Comment: This is one of those questions which should give more information about the greater picture. What is the problem you want to solve by creating hidden files with safe_mode=on (that would be a shared hosting enviroment)? Why do you care to have hidden files on a shared hosting enviroment?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `system()` to modify files on the server.

See: [PHP windows create hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935614/php-windows-create-hidden-files)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without `system()` or `exec()` as PHP doesn't have a function to do this. Using system is quite straight forward, for example:

```
$file = 'myfile.txt';
system('attrib +h ' . escapeshellarg($file));
```