# PHP: Save file as hidden in Windows, Linux (and MacOS?) respectively

Tags: php

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, as I'm no expert in PHP or file systems. I'm looking to create a hidden, read-only file in PHP. The major roadblock is that I can't find a cross-platform method to create a hidden file in all Operating Systems using PHP. This is as far as I got: [PHP windows create hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935614/php-windows-create-hidden-files)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: whats the big picture? are you serving the file via a web-server?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want the file to be hidden?

Comment: probably trying to hide a reverse shell script

Comment: The file I'm trying to create is a dynamically created output based on a CSS PHP file. Another option would be if anyone knows how to "find and replace all" PHP file without overwriting the source file.

Comment: well that makes even lees sense than the original question

Comment: I'd prefer to know how to create a hidden file instead for other projects in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UNIX like systems, adding a dot(".") before the file name will hide the file from the user.
In Windows systems, adding a H attribute to a file, it will also be hidden from the user.

Try This:

```
<?php

$system_info = posix_uname();
$sysname = $system_info["sysname"];
echo $sysname;

$file = "file.txt";

if ($sysname == "Linux" or $sysname == "Darwin") {
    $file = "." . $file;
} elseif (strpos($sysname, "Windows") == false) {
    system('attrib +H ' . escapeshellarg($file));
}

echo $file;

?>
```

**To deny access for files that starts with a dot in Apache,** add the following lines to the apache configuration file:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

To also deny access for folders that starts with a dot in Apache, add the following lines to the apache configuration file **with the lines above.**

```
<DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Will apache deliver the file in all instances?

Comment: Okay, with some very slight modifications, this worked. Although I am having some issues implementing it into my current script, although I'm sure I'll find a solution.

Comment: I have added a solution for the Apache problem in the solution above.

Comment: Update: Got everything working. Thanks for the help. I needed the files hidden as an easy means not to index the files using a recursive file listing. Sorry I didn't make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

"Hidden file" is just a way to describe files that give a recommendation to file explorers to not display them. You won't achieve anything securitywise with that. Use the file rights, e.g. set it to readable only by owner / group etc.

Filenames starting with a dot are considered hidden in Unix AND INDEPENDENTLY are not served by major servers like nginx and apache.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and basic solution you can set the filename to have a dot prefix, e.g. ".hiddenfile.ext" - this will stop the file showing up in regular (user requested) directory listings in most instances but it's by no means a full solution.

It's hard to answer fully though, as there's no background in the question for where you want to save the files, or for what purpose.